# not returning the right print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, the function returns a new string that has the telephone number with any alphabetic characters that appeared in the original translated to their numeric equivalent. Format of: XXX-XXX-XXXX.

This is my functions code:

```
def translate_phone(xxx):
phonenumber = ''
for alpha in xxx:
    if  alpha =='A' or alpha =='B' or alpha == 'C' :
        phonenumber.append('2')
    elif alpha == 'D' or alpha == 'E' or alpha =='F':
        phonenumber.append('3')
    elif alpha == 'G' or alpha =='H' or alpha =='I':
        phonenumber.append('4')
    elif alpha == 'J' or alpha =='K' or alpha =='L':
        phonenumber.append('5')
    elif alpha == 'M' or alpha == 'N' or alpha =='O':
        phonenumber.append('6')
    elif alpha == 'P' or alpha =='Q' or alpha =='R' or alpha =='S':
        phonenumber.append('7')
    elif alpha == 'T' or alpha =='U' or alpha =='V':
        phonenumber.append('8')
    elif alpha == 'W' or alpha =='X' or alpha == 'Y' or alpha =='Z':
        phonenumber.append('9')
    phonenumber = phonenumber + alpha
print(phonenumber)
```

This is my Main Code in another module:

```
from _functions import translate_phone
xxx = input('Enter the Number in the following format XXX-XXX-XXXX: ')
xxx = xxx.split('-')
translate_phone(xxx)
```

Error? Everytime I run it I get the same input back.

```
Enter the Number in the following format XXX-XXX-XXXX: ABC-123-QWER
ABC123QWER
```

Would appreciate if someone could hint what I'm doing wrong or just simply correct my mistake.

Comment: `xxx.split('-')` never returns `A` or any other letters. That's why you never enter in your if statements. Then string doesn't have append method...

Comment: Okay, I've done that and basically made my phonenumber = [] and this is my sample output now: Enter the Number in the following format XXX-XXX-XXXX: ALC-LOL-123
[2, 5, 2, 5, 6, 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need remove the code `xxx = xxx.split('-')` and replace your function for this:

```
def translate_phone(xxx):
  phonenumber = list()
  for alpha in xxx:
      if  alpha in ('A', 'B', 'C'):
          phonenumber.append('2')
      elif alpha in ('D', 'E', 'F'):
          phonenumber.append('3')
      elif alpha in ('G', 'H', 'I'):
          phonenumber.append('4')
      elif alpha in ('J', 'K', 'L'):
          phonenumber.append('5')
      elif alpha in ('M', 'N', 'O'):
          phonenumber.append('6')
      elif alpha in ('P', 'Q', 'R', 'S'):
          phonenumber.append('7')
      elif alpha in ('T', 'U', 'V'):
          phonenumber.append('8')
      elif alpha in ('W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'):
          phonenumber.append('9')
      else:
          phonenumber.append(alpha)
  return ''.join(phonenumber)
```

or

```
def translate_phone(xxx):
  phonenumber = list()
  for alpha in xxx:
      phonenumber.append(\
              '2' if alpha in ('A', 'B', 'C') else \
              '3' if alpha in ('D', 'E', 'F') else \
              '4' if alpha in ('G', 'H', 'I') else \
              '5' if alpha in ('J', 'K', 'L') else \
              '6' if alpha in ('M', 'N', 'O') else \
              '7' if alpha in ('P', 'Q', 'R', 'S') else \
              '8' if alpha in ('T', 'U', 'V') else \
              '9' if alpha in ('W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z') else alpha)
  return ''.join(phonenumber)
```